# How to move a Panasonic kx-t7633 Phone

Tags: local-area-network, pbx, telephone, phone

We have Panasonic kx-T7633 phones and I need to move them across office how do I activate or fix the connection after I move the phone Looked at the manual but no answers and googled it as well any help appreciated

Phone Model is Panasonic KX-T7633, Phone Type is: Digital Proprietary Telephone,

Comment: Unplug phone, move phone, plug phone in? - Seriously though, is this a digital keyset or an IP phone?

Comment: Telephone type is DPT [We have IP phones also unfortunately not this one ><]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually use these exact phones in my office. The phone is patched directly back to the PBX, and phone settings such as ext and name are configured at the PBX port level. You will need to locate the patch panel port that your phone is plugged into, and patch into the same port on your PBX when you swap it to retain the ext and what not.

Comment: Thanks For Reply: Here is more detail: You are correct but still stuck: there are two box panasonic kx TVA 200 and Panasonic Kx NCP 1000[this is the one that has all the ports and so far every single of them are connected to the patch panel for pbx, no link light system ><] I also was able to figure out existing the port number for that specific user/unit via kx-ncp maintenance panel on the pbx patch panel] any tool and technique?

Comment: @DanBig - This is actually true of any digital set, technically.  Keeping the same "cable" from pbx to handset throughout will retain the settings.  Do you happen to know how to do it by just moving the phone itself?  Is there a way to deregister the phone from the port on the PBX and then register it on the new port?  It would make it easier, especially if there are multiple line cards, etc.

Comment: @TheCleaner, our system is dated, and the only way we can make changes without swapping the cable is via CLI through a Hyper Terminal window at the PBX, and I simply cannot recall that info.

Comment: @DanBig - no worries, I just thought it could help someone like the OP in the future.  Telecom is a whole other animal, no doubt.

Comment: The Pbx patch panel was a mess not labeled although in the pbx box kx NCP 1000 all the ports were filled and seemed to connected respectivly on the patch panel but it wasn't connected [Big Dan and Joeqwerty were correct! Thanks a lot]

Answer (score 1):

Typically m/a/c to phones like registering/unregistering etc. can be done through the PBX admin interfaces themselves.  Most phones also allow you to enter "codes" on the phones for manual registration/de-registration if you choose to do so.

It's probably unlikely that you'll get a lot of telecom help here, so I'm posting this as possibilities from my google-fu:

> ```
> 1. Press PROGRAM * * or PROGRAM * # followed by the system password ( default is 1234).
> 2. Now press 004 and then ENTER.
> 3. Enter the extension number you want to change.
> 4. Enter the name (the same way as texting on a cellphone)
> 5. To save the changes press AUTO DIAL / STORE.
> 6. To go to the next extension press NEXT on the screen.
> 7. Lift the handset and put it down to exit program mode.
> ```

and looking here:

http://www.americasphoneguys.com/resources.html

There's some resources based on the various models and PBX's involved.  Honestly though, if you don't have a telecom resource that knows your system enough to even move a single phone extension to another desk, then you really need to get trained on doing these basic m/a/c's in-house.

EDIT: http://www.americasphoneguys.com/images/kx-ncp_userguide.pdf

According to that document the below will program an existing extension to be a new extension:

[image]

Also see here, where they describe something called "walking extension":

http://www.kxtsystem.com/NCP/data/fm_ncp1000/id_fm_ncp1000_0459.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply any books, resource or links you recommend to learn about this

Comment: @zman - I've updated my answer with some more info.  Sorry, I don't know this model pbx, so that's about the most help I can give.

Comment: Np Thanks for trying unfortunately I can't do the steps bc the phone wouldn't even turn on in the new port [live/dead port issue as well] can't trouble shoot it like regular lan ><

Answer (score 1):

It's been awhile since I've done a phone move but if this is a digital keyset then it usually follows that the output from the PBX for this keyset/extension is patched to a patch panel that feeds a particular wall jack. When moving the keyset to another wall jack you usually need to move the patch cable for that keyset to the new wall jack.

Comment: How to mark multiple answers correct??

Comment: Glad to help and glad you got it sorted. I'm happy to let DanBig have this one. :)